# MS Graph API and DriveItem search not working with client credentials flow

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, adal

I'm trying to call the search endpoint of the OneDrive API on a drive (i.e. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='mysearchterm')`. 
This works fine on the Graph Explorer, however, I'm not getting any search results with the client credentials flow on the same drive.

My app registration has all the required application permissions mentioned in the API documentation (`Files.Read.All`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `Sites.Read.All`, `Sites.ReadWrite.All`) and reading drives, driveitems, downloading drive items is all working fine. The one thing that is not working, is searching on drive items. I'm just getting an empty array back, no errors;

`{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)","value":[]}`

I'm using **adal-node** with `acquireTokenWithClientCredentials`.

```
var adal = require("adal-node");

const TENANT = "{tenant-name-here}.onmicrosoft.com";
const CLIENT_ID = "{Application-id-here}";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "{Application-key-here}";

function getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const authContext = new adal.AuthenticationContext(
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT}`
    );

    authContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
      GRAPH_URL,
      CLIENT_ID,
      CLIENT_SECRET,
      (err, tokenRes) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(tokenRes.accessToken);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

The drive I'm searching on is a SharePoint document library.

Answer (score 0):

**Some important tip**: client credentials flow need to register the app in the  [Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) but not [Applicaation Registeration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/). Graph Explorer is mostly based on the later one, so they have different backend code now is normal. Maybe they will do the same logic in furture.

> We strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources. Our development efforts are now concentrated on Microsoft Graph and no further enhancements are planned for Azure AD Graph API. There are a very limited number of scenarios for which Azure AD Graph API might still be appropriate; for more information, see the Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph blog post in the Office Dev Center.

adal-node is not the same as Graph, so you get result in the graph explorer but not the NodeJS product. We suggest you to use the latest Graph API.

Official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/activedirectory?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: I'm actually using the Microsoft Graph instead of the Azure AD Graph API. I'm only providing the code sample for adal-node to make clear that the client credentials flow does not provide the same results as the Graph API Explorer website does. The URL's used for requests are 100% identical, only the response is not.

Comment: their backend code not the same, so return value have some different. Most time, use the token from Azure AD Graph API doesn't work for the latest Graph API.

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same path here. There is no Azure AD Graph API being used here. The Microsoft Graph API is used to search on DriveItems (both in my code and the Graph API Explorer, [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)). Authentication is based on the OAuth client credentials flow with tokens issued by Azure AD. So no Azure AD Graph API at all.

Comment: So you need to provide the code you actual used but not the adal-node code. The code will mislead the guy who want to help you.

Comment: The adal-node code mentioned refers to fetching a bearer token via Azure AD based on the OAuth 2.0 credential flow. It has its purpose to illustrate the authentication method since my assumption is that this is part of the whole issue.

Comment: If you get started with the official sample and change the logic code to search driveitem, it should work. So the key point in your question is not the driveitem search not working with client credentials flow but the adal-node doesn't suit your requirement. I think not just me think like this. Your code not for the latest Graph Auth flow. The link I provided is not MS suggested now. MS suggest us to use the latest API.